# d3 equivalent for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js

I am looking to build a data visualization front-end for my company.  d3.js looks amazing, but I was hoping to find something more Rails-centric and perhaps slightly less complicated.  Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2):

With regards to your first question, as long as you create an endpoint which will return your data as JSON, any web app can be used with d3.

I think if you just want to add charts, something like [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/examples.html) which is based on d3 but comes with generalized charts pre-made is a good alternative. If you want to avoid using svg, http://www.chartjs.org/ is another good alternative which uses a `canvas` element.